# Autopopulate of foreign key string fields

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm currently changed the type of a primary key from `int` to `string` and all foreign keys accordingly. But unfortunately autopopulation of foreign key fields don't work now anymore.

Old (works fine):

```
context.Employees.Add(new Employee
{
    Name = "John",
    Addresses = {new Address {Details = "10 Van Riper Rd,Montvale, NJ 07645"}}
});
```

New (is broken):

```
context.Employees.Add(new Employee
{
    Id = "q123456",
    Name = "John",
    Addresses = {new Address {Details = "10 Van Riper Rd,Montvale, NJ 07645"}}
});
```

I got a `DbEntityValidationException` which told me that *"The EmployeeId field is required"* on entity `Address`.

Did I miss a setting or an attribute? Or is it simply impossible?

---

For your information, here's my `DbContext` modification:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
        .HasMany(employee => employee.Addresses)
        .WithRequired()
        .HasForeignKey(address => address.EmployeeId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

Comment: I would assume that because you are specifying the `Id` of the parent `Employee`, and adding its addresses at the same time, you also need to specify the `EmployeeId` in the child `Address`. So either don't set the IDs anywhere if it is autogenerated, or set it everywhere if it is manually generated. I can't find any docs for this tho

Comment: @Rhumborl Yes, you may be right. A `context.SaveChanges();` between adding the `Employee` and the employee's `Address` does the job. If that's the only solution for manually generated keys I'll swallow the bitter pill. Thanks anyway!

Comment: So even just changing your "new" code you posted to `Addresses = {new Address {EmployeeId = "q123456", Details = "10 Van Riper Rd,Montvale, NJ 07645" } }` doesn't work?

Comment: @Rhumborl Oh yes, that works. Sorry! I didn't consider that because my focus was on letting Entity Framework work ;-)